# cvCreateFileCapture returns a null value

Tags: c, opencv, video, ubuntu-12.04, video-capture

On execution the following code always shows `No video found`.

It is entering the loop as well since I checked it by putting a test message. Although,  the program is running fine without any errors but I am not getting the desired video output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("Example2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture* capture1 = cvCreateFileCapture("~/home/abhimanyu/sample_video.mp4");
    if(capture1 == NULL)
    printf("No video found");   
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture1);
        if(!frame) break;
        cvShowImage("Example2",frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if(c == 27) break;

        printf("Inside the loop\n");
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture1);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2"); 
    enter code here
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I guess you should replace `~/home/abhimanyu/sample_video.mp4` for `/home/abhimanyu/sample_video.mp4`.

Comment: i am still facing the same problem can there be some issues with the libraries???

Comment: I don't believe. Did you replace, recompile and test? Because, in your  code the path was wrong.

Comment: Either the video path is wrong or the video format is not supported by OpenCV. Try the code on some other format like `avi`.

Comment: i checked the path and used the path you suggested still no help.And I asked you about libraries since on the net I read some querries and one of them implied that there could be a problem with linking of ffmpeg libraries.What do you say??

Comment: And I am just a beginner in opencv.I am using it in the ubuntu platform.Can you suggest me a site that would deal with opencv systematically from ubunnt's point of view.

Comment: @sgar91 Thanks!!! there were issues with using mp4 format.Worked fine with avi files